# Do I really need SuspsensionManager in Win-RT Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

My ViewModel loads its state by itself on demand and saves part of its state when something changes.

Windows RT apps have something called the SuspsensionManager. This seems to load and save state only on the suspended and activated events. I personally prefer my model which is simple to understand and only saves and loads individual properties on my view model on demand.

So do I really need the SuspsensionManager? It seems to be doing somethign with the Frame which I can't quite get my head around. Is it possible to remove the SessionManager altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the SuspsensionManager class, no, you don't have to use it.  It is a convenience class provided by the Visual Studio project templates and is consumed by the LayoutAwarePage base class which is in turn used by the various page templates like "Basic Page", "Split Page", "Item Page", "Item Detail Page", "Grouped Items Page" and "Group Detail Page".

LayoutAwarePage adds support for saving state (using the SuspensionManager) on navigation and lifecycle events, as well as support for the Snapped and Filled Visual States, and even a basic ViewModel implementation.

You could choose to use the "Blank Page" template as you add new pages to your app. You are then free to implement your own session state, visual states, MVVM, etc. as you wish.